# How to get the value of a specific row in a table in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I get the value of a specific row in a table in VueJS 2?
This is my table right now [image: now]

Below is my code to generate a table and two buttons that will show a modals; one is to edit detail and the other is to show the QR Code coming from the database. I want to get the last **value** of the loop and put it in **SHOW QR Button** and the Show QR Button will contain the last value from the loop.

```
<div class="myTable table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Member ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="result in filteredList" :key="result.id">
        <td>{{result.Memb_ID}}</td>
        <th>{{result.First_Name}}</th>
        <th>{{result.Middle_Name}}</th>
        <th>{{result.Last_Name}}</th>
        <th>{{result.Address}}</th>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <b-button v-b-modal.showDetails size="lg" class="showDetails" variant="danger">Edit</b-button>
          <b-button v-b-modal.modalQR size="lg" class="showQR" variant="success">Show QR</b-button>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is my modal where I want to have different QR for every user to be inserted.  [image: here]
Below is my modal for the **Show QR Button**

```
<b-modal id="modalQR" title="Generated Details">
    <div class="showQR text-center">
      <qrcode-vue :value="results.url" :size="size" level="H"></qrcode-vue>
    </div>
  </b-modal>
```

and below is my script[image: here is m]

```
 <script>
import QrcodeVue from "qrcode.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      results: {},
      value: "",
      size: 200,
      selected: [],

    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.results.filter(post =>
        post.First_Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  },
  methods: {

    getUsers() {
      axios
        .get("localhost:9000/user/")
        .then(response => (this.results = response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    }
  },
  components: {
    QrcodeVue
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUsers();
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-for` also gives you the index of the item you're on:

```
<tr v-for="(result, index) in filteredList" :key="result.id">
```

Then you can just use `index === filteredList.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<tr v-for="result in filteredList.data" :key="result.id">
        <td>{{result.Memb_ID}}</td>
```

Comment: you are just using vuejs or vuejs+laravel or vuejs+php please provide the extra code